# What is the current Status of major proposed BTC upgrades like Taproot, MAST, Submarine Swaps?

Tags: lightning-network, bip, schnorr-signatures, taproot

I have read during the last year about some very interesting BIPs or initiatives. I am not asking for their explanations, just would be great if anyone would know about their simple **status** as of now, whether they are still considered to be implemented at some point (do you know **when?**), or whether they have been removed from consideration...

1)  MAST

2)  TAPROOT

3)  SCHNORR

4)  Submarine Swaps

5)  Consumer Lightning-based applications (desktop+mobile by Jack Mallers)

6)  Drivechain Sidechain, by Paul Sztorc

7)  Lightning over NFC, by Igor Cota

I just dont know where to track those initiatives .

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

1) MAST: Essentially folded into Taproot

2) Taproot: Planned to be part of the upcoming SegWit V1 softfork. A formal proposal for that has been about two weeks away for half a year, so could appear any day now. ;)

3) Schnorr: All SegWit V1 transactions will only allow Schnorr signatures and no ECDSA signatures. I am not sure whether the first release of Schnorr signatures will include any form of signature aggregation beyond the one used in correspondence with public key aggregation, i.e. making multisig look like singlesig.

4) AFAIU, Submarine Swaps have been implemented in both directions. The variant from chain to Lightning has been live for a while and Lightning Lab's Lightning Loop has greatly simplified offering Lightning to on-chain transition.

5) Lightning Network is mostly for masochists, enthusiasts, and experts still. If you're attempting to dive-in at this time, I would suggest to bring a good amount of frustration tolerance. ;)

6) I talked to Paul about that a bit a few weeks ago. He's making progress. There are some disagreements on whether or not he has been able to solve the challenges that caused other sidechain projects to be severely delayed. I am not sure whether deployment requires a softfork, but the drivechain doesn't appear to have achieved broad interest at this time.

7) I know nothing about Lightning over NFC.

---

All of the above from the top of my head and probably in dire need of corrections and/or substantiation. Will edit as people tell me where I'm wrong. :)